# My program "stuck in this line" reading stream

Tags: vb.net, stream

This

So I am reading a stream like usual. Then it just stuck. It doesn't throw exception or anything. It just stucks.

```
            Try
                Do
                    read = stream.Read(datain, 0, datain.Length) 'Stuck here
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(datain, 0, read)
                    finalResponse = finalResponse + responseData
                Loop While read > 0
            Catch ex As Exception
```

What should I do so that the program would never get stuck like that? Notice I already put the code inside try catch block

Here is the full program.

```
  Public Function getWhoisInfoAsText4(strDomainName As String, whoisServerToTry As String) As String
        'testAsisWhois()
        Dim data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strDomainName & Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbCr & Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbLf)
        Dim finalResponse = String.Empty
        Dim client As TcpClient
        Try
            client = New TcpClient(whoisServerToTry, 43)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try

        Dim stream = client.GetStream()
        Using stream

            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

            Dim datain = New Byte(254) {}
            Dim responseData = String.Empty
            Dim read As Integer
            Try
                Do
                    read = stream.Read(datain, 0, datain.Length)
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(datain, 0, read)
                    finalResponse = finalResponse + responseData
                Loop While read > 0
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Using

        If finalResponse.Contains("Name Server:") Then
            appendToTextFile(whoisServerToTry + vbNewLine, "appendfiles", Scripting.IOMode.ForAppending)
        End If

        finalResponse += (whoisServerUsed + whoisServerToTry + vbNewLine)
        Return finalResponse
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

does your program stuck at the first loop sequence?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mabye this should help

```
            Dim numBytesRead as Integer = 0 
            Do
                read = stream.Read(datain, numBytesRead, datain.Length)
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(datain, 0, read)
                finalResponse = finalResponse + responseData
                numBytesRead += read
            Loop While read > 0
```

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: second argument in stream.Read

Comment: I put 0 there. You put an integer whose value is 0?

Comment: which is increased with the value of read after the first stream read, thats why i asked you if your program already stucks at the first loop

Answer (score 1):

**Stream.Read** waits always until the amount of bytes it is expecting is coming, if there is an interruption on the communication just in the moment the program is exactly on the **Read** and the connection get close the program will be forever in this point waiting for the rest of the bytes to come unless you will configure a **ReadTimeout**, then after not receiving any bytes during this time it will throw an exception. 
You should then make a try catch and restart the connection.